# Find most recently modified file in a directory

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

What would be a good way, via the Bash command-line, to find the time of the last modification made to any of the files in a particularly directory?

Basically, I'm working on a project where all the project's files are within one directory, and I'm keeping a timesheet, and I forgot to note when I finished working on the project earlier today.  Whichever file was modified last will give me that time.

I could guess at the time... but I thought it would be fun to get Bash to give me a more accurate answer :)

As an added bonus, I think the command will likely need to ignore certain directories, in particular the .git directory in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're after, but this should work for quick checks:

```
ls -tl
```

Comment: I usually use ls -ltr so that the newest are at the bottom, it makes it easy to see them when there's a lot of files scrolling by.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer `ls -lrt`, especially if there are lots of files.  The `t` says to sort by modification time, and the `r` says to reverse the sort.  This way the newest files are listed last, and will still be in the window without scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

To narrow down a guess (here 50 minutes ago) while looking recursively in a directory structure and excluding a couple of paths:

```
find -name .git -prune -o -name another_exclusion -prune -o \( -newermt "now - 50 min" -ls \)
```